# Hashbang URLs (#!) problems in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, hashbang

Good Morning Everybody,

I have my site in wordpress, now the issue is that google index one of my Hashbang url like below…

> http://example.com/#!info/citr

I don't know whether it is present in my site or not....and unable to find such kind of any url in my site...

Due to above Hashbang url google shows duplicate content issue…

I want to redirect above url to home page url, is there any way to redirect url include Hashbang(#!) to home page, like below…

> http://example.com/#!info/citr

Should redirect to

> http://example.com

Please reply me….

Comment: go to settings->permalinks, set default permalink. and visit that page.

Comment: sir, i am using permalinks as below...

settings->permalinks->/%postname%/ (Post Name)

but problem is still there...

Comment: try to set theme default and one by one deactive your plugin

Comment: https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-find-and-fix-broken-wordpress-links